# How to insert metadata to AVMutableComposition instance on the runtime without writing to file

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation

My goal is to arm AVMutableComposition variable with some additional metadata. This composition is not the subject of writing to the file. It's purpose is to play in AVPlayer as an AVAsset. It is generated on the runtime based on information in database.

I need to add some typical metadata to this composition. Is it possible to do this without using AVExportSession or AVAssetWriter?